# Getting More than one contacts in the edittexts

Tags: android, android-contacts

Here there are many links provided for getting contacts using contact picker.But they all work for a single edit text.I have three editTexts and I want every editText should be filled with help of contacts picker.I am new to android please help me how can I do this?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxT4Sf_ySmmMTHRkcjAtWWtQdjQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Here in onActivityResult we have to setup the text for the edit text
but there are 4 edittexts in the activity an onActivity will setText for only one EditText according to any link provide here.I googled a lot but no help.